# Drupal 7 theme template file names not working

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7

I have extensively read many articles and the Drupal docs on how to create Drupal 7 theme templates, but for some reason none of the recommendations are working.

I have fresh install as of Friday, I have uninstalled all Modules. I have only created 3 basic page with a machine name of "page", a Content Type with the machine name of "staffers". I have my wrapper in page.tpl.php, which is working.

I can get the staffers content type to work only if I use node--nid.tpl.php ("node--6.tpl.php"), however I can not get node--staffers.tpl.php to work.

Additionally page--id.., or node-id.. will not work for the "page" content so I can't even figure how I can write a single custom template for each page id I want, or an overall template for the "staffers" content type.

I have nothing coded in my template.php at this point, and even with customethemename_preprocess_node being added I was unable to load the page--front.tpl.php I read about once.

So how do I get Drupal to load the template by nid or machine name for pages and custom content types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drupal-7, page--front.tpl.php should be appeared by default. You can check whether you have uninstalled any core module or not.

Comment: Nice call. I turned on "Forum", and went ahead and turned on "CCK". Working now smh. Thanks a bunch!